# How to set the CSS from Javascript of a dynamic data

Tags: javascript, css, google-app-maker

I want to set the 'status' label and their css font-color base on their validity  and tried the following:

```
/**
 * To return status and set their label color according to expiration date
 */

function getStatusName(DueDate) {

  var a = app.pages.Dashboard.descendants.Table2Body.children.Table2Row.children.status;

  var status = 'Valid';

  if (DueDate < new Date()) {
    status = 'Expired';
  }

  switch(status) {
    case 'Valid':
        a.styles.color = green;
        break;
    case 'Expired':
        a.styles.color = red;
        break;
    default:
        return;
  }

  return status;
}
```

The label work except for setting the color of that label. What is the correct way to set the CSS in Js? This is one of my Server Script in Google App Maker.

Comment: What is `a` in this context?

Comment: $('#Your-label name').css('color', 'your-color-code');  this is currect way to set css in js :)

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya jquery != js

Comment: this is js, 'a' is the variable that reference to 'status' label

Comment: Is your 'status' just a label in the table, or is the status a data field? The reason your color doesn't work is because element.styles points to an array of strings of which CSS classes to apply to the element. To fix this you would need to do a.getElement().style.color = 'green'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather go with the binding for the label's styles property:

```js
@datasource.item.DueDate < new Date() ? ['green'] : ['red']
```

and couple CSS classes:

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

same trick should work for the label's text binding:

```js
@datasource.item.DueDate < new Date() ? 'Valid' : 'Expired'
```

Comment: thanks bro it works! but if got another condition eg. 'Pending' then can't use this one right? or got another way to do it?

Comment: You'll just have more states => need more CSS classes => you'll need a function to handle it. Take a look at Travel Approval template, it does something very similar for request statuses - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/travel-approval/

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work if a is the correct element (difference with your code being "style" instead of "styles" and encapsulating the css value in double quote) :

```
/**
 * To return status and set their label color according to expiration date
 */

function getStatusName(DueDate) {

  var a = app.pages.Dashboard.descendants.Table2Body.children.Table2Row.children.status;

  var status = 'Valid';

  if (DueDate < new Date()) {
    status = 'Expired';
  }

  switch(status) {
    case 'Valid':
        a.style.color = "green";
        break;
    case 'Expired':
        a.style.color = "red";
        break;
    default:
        return;
  }

  return status;
}
```

More information : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: 'a' is the 'status' label & I am pretty sure it is correct but changing 'styles' to 'style' still didn't work for me tough

Comment: It would seem that the line of code under the switch statement needs to be changed to a.getElement().style.color